# Windows Installer per-user installation context folder redirection requirements

Tags: wix, windows-installer

**TL;DR:** I cannot get the `%ProgramFiles%` to `%LocalAppData%\Programs` folder redirection [documented by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installation-context) by simply ensuring that the `ALLUSERS` property is empty.

Is that folder redirection only achievable in [dual-purpose packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/single-package-authoring) by setting `ALLUSERS=2` and `MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1`, and does that mean that [Microsoft's documentation on installation context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installation-context) is wrong?

---

I'm using Wix v4 to create an installer based on Windows Installer technology. The installer must not require elevated privileges and therefore install the application for the current user only, not all users.

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installation-context), I can point my installation location to `ProgramFiles64` and, if I did not set the `ALLUSERS` property, it will automatically redirect the folder to a standard user-writable location, which has been `%LocalAppData%\Programs` since at least Windows 7.

The equivalent of that is to user the `perUser` scope in WiX, which will not set `ALLUSERS` (and also disable privilege escalation).
This is what my test package looks like:

```xml
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <Package Name="Contoso App" Manufacturer="Contoso" Version="$(ProductVersion)" UpgradeCode="a58f9a69-c688-46f1-8c8e-eb225060c61c" Scope="perUser">
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <StandardDirectory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.Property.ProductName)" />
    </StandardDirectory>

    <ComponentGroup Id="ExampleComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component>
        <File Id="ContosoApp.exe" Source="$(env.USERPROFILE)\ContosoApp\bin\ContosoApp.exe" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

    <Feature Id="Main">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ExampleComponents" />
    </Feature>
  </Package>
</Wix>
```

Unfortunately, the installer compiled from that tries to install to `C:\Program Files\Contoso App` and not `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Contoso App`

If I change the scope to `perUserOrMachine`, then I get the redirection.
That's also equivalent to adding this to the above example within the `<Package>` element:

```xml
<Property Id="ALLUSERS" Secure="yes" Value="2" />
<Property Id="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Secure="yes" Value="1" />
```

But I'm not really looking to create a dual-purpose package as Microsoft calls them. I just want a single-purpose one that only ever installs per user and can never ask for privilege escalation.

Am I missing something?